# Problem using useDispatch Hook - Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

This is my first time using Redux Hooks in react.-native, but I am having trouble in my test because when I run the test i get this Warning:

> Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by
>   WarrantiesHomeButton. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed.
>   For more information, read the Rules of Hooks:
>
> ```
>    Previous render            Next render
>    ------------------------------------------------------
> 1. useState                   useContext
>    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

I am not sure if the problem is my code or the way I am testing i, the application is running fine. If I run each test independently , the test pass without Warning, if I run all three tests, the last test throw the warning and error.

I would appreciate if you guys could point me to the right direction where I am making a mistake.

WarrantiesHomeButton.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { WarrantiesHomeMenu } from '../WarrantiesHomeMenu';
import { userService } from '../services';
import { HomeButton } from '../components';
import { screenNames } from '../constants';
import { userActions } from '../store';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const WarrantiesHomeButton = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [showWarrantiesMenu, setShowWarrantiesMenu] = useState(false);

  const { warrantiesLoginFlow, user } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.userReducer,
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handlePressWarranties = () => {
    if (!userService.isAuthenticated()) {
      dispatch(userActions.warrantiesLoginStart());
      navigation.navigate(screenNames.SIGN_UP);
    } else {
      setShowWarrantiesMenu(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    validateWarrantiesFlow();
  });

  const validateWarrantiesFlow = useCallback(() => {
    if (warrantiesLoginFlow && user.id) {
      setShowWarrantiesMenu(true);
      dispatch(userActions.warrantiesLoginStop());
    }
  }, [warrantiesLoginFlow, user.id, dispatch]);

  const handleModalPress = () => {
    setShowWarrantiesMenu(false);
    navigation.navigate(screenNames.SERVICE_CENTERS);
  };

  const closeWarrantiesHomeMenu = () => {
    setShowWarrantiesMenu(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <HomeButton
        testID="HomeButton"
        text="Revisiones garantía"
        icon="toolBox"
        onPress={handlePressWarranties}
      />

      <WarrantiesHomeMenu
        visible={showWarrantiesMenu}
        onPress={handleModalPress}
        navigation={navigation}
        closeModal={closeWarrantiesHomeMenu}
      />
    </>
  );
};

WarrantiesHomeButton.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
};

export { WarrantiesHomeButton };
```

WarrantiesHomeButton.test.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {
  render as rtlRender,
  fireEvent,
  wait,
  act,
} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { userService } from '../services';
import { screenNames } from '../constants';
import { WarrantiesHomeButton } from './WarrantiesHomeButton';
import { store } from '@auteco/store';

jest.mock('@auteco/components', () => require('@auteco/test').mockComponents());

jest.mock('../WarrantiesHomeMenu', () => {
  const { mockComponent } = require('@auteco/test');
  return {
    WarrantiesHomeMenu: mockComponent('WarrantiesHomeMenu'),
  };
});

describe('<WarantiesHomeButton/>', () => {
  let mockProps;
  const setState = jest.fn();
  beforeAll(() => {
    mockProps = {
      navigation: {
        navigate: jest.fn(),
        dangerouslyGetParent: jest.fn(() => ({ state: null })),
      },
    };
    jest.spyOn(userService, 'isAuthenticated').mockReturnValue(true);
  });

  function render(ui) {
    return rtlRender(<Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>);
  }

  it('Should Render correctly', () => {
    const { baseElement } = render(<WarrantiesHomeButton {...mockProps} />);
    expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  describe('And user is authenticated', () => {
    describe('And button is pressed', () => {
      it('Should show WarrantiesMenu by setting setShowWarrantiesMenu state to true', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockReturnValue([false, setState]);
        const { getByTestId } = render(<WarrantiesHomeButton {...mockProps} />);
        const button = getByTestId('HomeButton');
        button.props.onPress();
        await wait();
        expect(setState).toBeCalledWith(true);
      });
    });
  });

  describe('And user is not authenticated', () => {
    describe('And button is pressed', () => {
      it('Should navigate to signUpScreen', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(userService, 'isAuthenticated').mockReturnValue(false);
        jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockReturnValue([false, setState]);
        const { getByTestId } = render(<WarrantiesHomeButton {...mockProps} />);
        const button = getByTestId('HomeButton');
        act(() => {
          button.props.onPress();
        });
        expect(mockProps.navigation.navigate).toBeCalledWith(
          screenNames.SIGN_UP,
        );
      });
    });
  });
});
```

error in console

```
  console.error node_modules/react-native/Libraries/YellowBox/YellowBox.js:63
    Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by WarrantiesHomeButton. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks

       Previous render            Next render
       ------------------------------------------------------
    1. useState                   useContext
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        in WarrantiesHomeButton
        in Provider
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by AppContainer)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by AppContainer)
        in AppContainer (at src/index.js:26)

  console.error node_modules/react-native/Libraries/YellowBox/YellowBox.js:63
    The above error occurred in the <WarrantiesHomeButton> component:
        in WarrantiesHomeButton
        in Provider
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by AppContainer)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by AppContainer)
        in AppContainer (at src/index.js:26)

    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.


 FAIL  src/components/home/WarrantiesHomeButton/WarrantiesHomeButton.test.js
  <WarantiesHomeButton/>
    ✓ Should Render correctly (55ms)
    And user is authenticated
      And button is pressed
        ✓ Should show WarrantiesMenu by setting setShowWarrantiesMenu state to true (12ms)
    And user is not authenticated
      And button is pressed
        ✕ Should navigate to signUpScreen (77ms)

  ● <WarantiesHomeButton/> › And user is not authenticated › And button is pressed › Should navigate to signUpScreen

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

      11 |   const [showWarrantiesMenu, setShowWarrantiesMenu] = useState(false);
      12 | 
    > 13 |   const { warrantiesLoginFlow, user } = useSelector(
         |                                         ^
      14 |     (state) => state.userReducer,
      15 |   );
      16 |   const dispatch = useDispatch();

      at areHookInputsEqual (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5703:38)
      at updateMemo (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6336:11)
      at Object.useMemo (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6703:16)
      at useMemo (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1592:21)
      at useSelectorWithStoreAndSubscription (node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useSelector.js:31:41)
      at useSelector (node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useSelector.js:117:12)
      at WarrantiesHomeButton (src/components/home/WarrantiesHomeButton/WarrantiesHomeButton.js:13:41)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5762:18)
      at updateFunctionComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7579:20)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9152:16)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        4.846s, estimated 5s
Ran all test suites matching /WarrantiesHomeButton/i.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useState                   useState
3. useState                   useState
4. useState                   useState
5. useContext                 useEffect
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I had a similar issue as you can observe above. I finally resolved it by wrapping the creation/rendering of each component in the `it` blocks in an `act`. It seems the asynchronous actions of `useEffect` on the component from the tests are clashing with each other. I resolved as indicated below:

```
let component: any;
await act(async () => {
  component = create(
    <MockedProvider>
      <SelectAccountScreen {...props} />
    </MockedProvider>,
  );
});
```

PS: I am using `react-test-renderer` (in case you are wondering where `create` came from)

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on this answer ? An example snippet of how you are using the component would be great too